# Angular $rootScope.on('$stateChangeStart') is not working

Tags: angularjs, debugging, angular-ui-router

I use [this](https://www.google.ro/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi62LmwmNPRAhUFJJoKHYrXA6IQFggYMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.laravel-angular.io%2F&usg=AFQjCNEwc4eZ-1ZdmYvmsYpVUu--l85V8A&sig2=frw0xMA9WG2Xg9i4WwJvmg&bvm=bv.144224172,d.bGs) to create my website and when i created a run method with $rootScope.on('$stateChangeStart') in it and isn't working.Here is the code:

```
.run('Url',function($rootScope, $state, $location){
    'ngInject' ;

    console.log('Is working');
    function message(to, toP, from, fromP) {
        return from.name  + angular.toJson(fromP) + " -> " + to.name + angular.toJson(toP);
    }
    $rootScope.$on("$stateChangeStart",   function(evt, to, toP, from, fromP)      {
        console.log("Start:   " + message(to, toP, from, fromP));
        console.log('Not working');
    });
```

First log when I load the website is working but the second two log are not ,any ideas where the problem is?

Answer (score 7):

If you change of version.

For the new ui-router (Angular 1.x version) . You need to load stateEvents file.

```
<script src="lib/angular-ui-router/release/stateEvents.min.js"></script>
```

add load it in your application

```
angular.module('MyApp', ['ui.router', 'ui.router.state.events', ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you use rootScope.$on like as

```
.run(['$rootScope', '$state', '$location',function($rootScope, $state, $location){  
         console.log('Is working');
         function message(to, toP, from, fromP) {
            return from.name  + angular.toJson(fromP) + " -> " + to.name + angular.toJson(toP);
       }
        $rootScope.$on("$stateChangeStart",   function(evt, to, toP, from, fromP)      {
            console.log("Start:   " + message(to, toP, from, fromP));
            console.log('Not working');
        })
    }]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this: '$viewContentLoading' or '$viewContentLoaded' :

```
$rootScope.$on('$viewContentLoading', function() {
    // your stuff here…
});
$rootScope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function() {
    // your stuff here…
});
```